# Como utiliza < como texto

Tags: html, html5, text

Gostaria de saber como eu poderia utilizar o simbolo como texto no meu código HTML por exemplo gostaria de escrever < O Majestoso > só que entre os símbolos de maior e menor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Os três caracteres ‘<’, ‘>’, e ‘&’ têm significados especiais em HTML, eles são utilizados no código dos documentos. Para utilizá-los no texto, utilize as seguintes entidades:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

< O Majestoso >

Só digitar assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: perfeito agradeço a vocês!

Answer (score 3):

Bom dia, Thales!

Tente da seguinte forma

```
&lt;O Majestoso&gt;
```

Dessa forma o navegador entende que esses caracteres não devem ser interpretados como uma *tag* `HTML`.

Para consultas futuras, você pode visitar http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/entities/special.html